# Defining constants in att syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

What would be the equivalent in att syntax for defining some easier-to-read constants at the top of a file?

```
SYS_READ   equ     0          ; read text from stdin
SYS_WRITE  equ     1          ; write text to stdout
SYS_EXIT   equ     60         ; terminate the program
STDIN      equ     0          ; standard input
STDOUT     equ     1          ; standard output
```

My thought would be something like:

```
.section .rodata
SYS_READ:    .byte     0
SYS_WRITE:   .byte     1
# ...
```

Is this correct or close? If not, what would be the suggested way to define a bunch of constants at the top of an assembly program?

Comment: Read the GAS manual, it has a `.equ` directive which is exactly equivalent.  Or a `SYS_READ = 0` syntax for assemble-time constants.  Obviously you don't want to put actual data into `.rodata`, that wouldn't be equivalent and you'd have to load it instead of using an immediate.

Comment: @PeterCordes in the above case, should I use: `sys_read=0` or `sys_read .equ 0` or define it in the `.rodata` section?

Comment: You should read the manual or the linked duplicates.  That's why I linked this question to them instead of writing a full answer in comments or as an answer.